# react-redus post api call err 404 not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello today I started working with redux so I am a beginner and I want to make my register request the API Is working perfectly I tested it with postman and also with normal fetch on a component without redux and worked so API is not the problem.

Basically, I want to send user data and get the token back I get 404 not found error in the console here is my code =>

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import { register } from './actions/auth'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function App({ register }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  return (
    <>
      <input placeholder="email" onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
      <input placeholder="username" onChange={(e) => { setUsername(e.target.value) }} />
      <input placeholder="password" onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }} />
      <button onClick={() => { register({ username, password, email }) }}>register</button>

    </>
  );
}

//todo proptypes

register.PropTypes = {
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, { register })(App);
```

```
// import
import axios from 'axios'
import { REGISTER_FAIL, REGISTER_SUCCESS } from './types'

//register user
export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => async dispatch => {

    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }

    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password })

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/register', body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL
        })
    }

}
```

```
import { REGISTER_FAIL, REGISTER_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: null
}


export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action

    switch (type) {
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem("token", payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                isAuthenticated: true
            }
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Is 3000 the right port for your API, and is your API allowing cross-origin requests?

Comment: You can set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) during development, I don't think `http://localhost` is something you want to use in code that will eventually run on a public server.

Comment: I fixed the problem and yeah I know I used only there localhost just to test thanks.